# C++ dll returns different results when called from Excel VBA/Python

Tags: c++, python-2.7, excel, vba

Suppose my VC100 Dll project has the following:

## Foo.h

```
struct Foo {
    std::vector v;
    ...

    Foo(const double* x, const long& n, ...)
        : v(x, x + n),
          ... {; }

    double bar() {...} // Does something to this->v, returns a double
};
```

## myproject.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"    

double fun(double* x, long n, ...) {
    
    Foo f(x, n, ...);

    const double r(f.bar());
    
    std::memcpy(x, f.v.data(), n * sizeof(double));
   
    return r;
}

inline double __stdcall xfun(double* x, long n, ...) {
    return fun(x, n, ...);
}
```

## def.def

```
library "myproject"
EXPORTS
fun
xfun
```

## mywb.xlsm (VBA)

```
Declare Function xl_fun Lib "myproject.dll" Alias "xfun" _
    (ByRef x As Double, ByVal n As Integer, ...) As Double
```

`xl_fun()` is then called from Excel, and `fun()` is called from Python 2.7` after.

My question is, `xl_fun()` will return with its first argument updated to the contents of `Foo.v`, just as Python will.

However, when `fun()` is called from `Python 2.7`, the first argument update, and the return value is different.

Without going into too much detail, this update and return are *better* numbers than the Excel ones.

All exceptions are handled by the time `f.bar()` returns.

I've stepped through and confirmed the inputs passed to `Foo`'s constructor are identical in both cases. I've also confirmed `Foo.v`'s initial state is identical in both cases. How can the same `DLL` produce different results given the same inputs?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel sets FPU flags for extended precision (80-bits) while most other run-time environments don't. This may play a role in the differences you observe.